# Heuristics for the word problem for monoids

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, semigroups-and-monoids

The question is about a purely practical problem:

Given is a list of identities, as in http://www.findstat.org/MapsDatabase/Mp00069:

```
Mp00069 ∘ Mp00069 = id : Permutations ⟶ Permutations
Mp00064 ∘ Mp00069 = Mp00069 ∘ Mp00064 : Permutations ⟶ Permutations
Mp00067 ∘ Mp00069 = Mp00069 ∘ Mp00067 : Permutations ⟶ Permutations
Mp00069 ∘ Mp00126 = Mp00126 ∘ Mp00069 : Permutations ⟶ Permutations
Mp00069 ∘ Mp00175 = Mp00175 ∘ Mp00069 : Permutations ⟶ Permutations
Mp00069 ∘ Mp00067 ∘ Mp00126 = Mp00067 ∘ Mp00126 ∘ Mp00069 : Permutations ⟶ Permutations
Mp00069 ∘ Mp00064 ∘ Mp00159 = Mp00159 ∘ Mp00069 ∘ Mp00064 : Permutations ⟶ Permutations
Mp00069 ∘ Mp00064 ∘ Mp00175 = Mp00064 ∘ Mp00175 ∘ Mp00069 : Permutations ⟶ Permutations
...
```

(in fact, the full list is the list of *all* identities in the monoid I want to consider, which involve at most 3 elements on either side of the equation)

I would like to have a heuristic (ideally: implemented), which removes the identities which follow from (eg. lexicographically) smaller identities.

For example,

`Mp00069 ∘ Mp00064 ∘ Mp00175 = Mp00064 ∘ Mp00175 ∘ Mp00069` follows from `Mp00064 ∘ Mp00069 = Mp00069 ∘ Mp00064` and `Mp00069 ∘ Mp00175 = Mp00175 ∘ Mp00069`.

Comment: (I looked at https://gap-packages.github.io/Semigroups and https://gap-packages.github.io/kbmag but didn't get anywhere, very likely because I don't know anything about the topic.)